# X509 certificates - Subject identifiers of arbitrary types like UUID

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle

What are other ways to add subject identifiers of arbitrary types in X509 certificates? Consider the following subject and its properties:

```
Person
- id: UUID
- username: String
- domain: String
- organizationName: String
```

I'm considering having the `username`, `domain`, and `organizationName` to form the subject DN. But what would be the ideal way to include the `id`, which is a UUID? Can we have it included on the Subject Alternative Name extension? If yes, what would be the `GeneralName` tag? If we can have it on the subject DN, what would be the appropriate RDN to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert the `UUID` as an OID and include it on the Subject Alternative Name extension as `GeneralName.RegisteredId`